# Transitioning from PhD in biomedical engineering to software dev (have 5-6 software experience working for a team during PhD)?

Tags: career-path, software

My PhD is in biomedical engineering (MEMS and electronics). I also have taken some CS classes in the last 5 years (and during undergrad in electrical engineering). I was also in the software team for a robotics club at university for the past 5 years. How do I market myself for SW jobs in industry?

Comment: Software is an important part of most engineering designs, particularly because of the rapid feedback, relatively low cost of fixing mistakes, and flexibility to introduce changes later in the design cycle.  There's no need to switch fields in order to become a programmer, and in quite a few vertical markets, knowledge of biomedical topics, MEMS, and/or electronics will help you understand the system you are programming and make you much more valuable than a mere CS major.  For that matter, depending on your location I could put you in touch with people who are hiring for positions like that.

Answer (score 0):

I have been in both industry and academia, both as a software developer and lecturer, and here two points that might help you:

1. **You Diplomas**: You non-software related diplomas, does not hold you back on finding good software development jobs. It is how much you know about software development. In fact, you have a good story on saying that you are chasing what you like.
2. **Choose Your Side**: Ok, so you been involved with robotics, so probably you enjoy logic and reasoning more than shapes and colors. Therefore I would suggest to look into back-end development sort of things (e.g., Python, Java development), rather than front-end design and implementation.
3. **Your CV**: In you cv include any software development experience, even if it is by using an obscure software or programming language. Also, do not hide your academic past, simply explain that is what you did enjoy then and now you enjoy doing software development.